# python urllib2 multi downloading

Tags: python, html, urllib

How would I make the below script download multiple links at once instead of one at a time with urllib2?

python:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import lxml.html as html
import urlparse
import os, sys
import urllib2
import re

print ("downloading and parsing Bibles...")
root = html.parse(open('links.html'))
for link in root.findall('//a'):
  url = link.get('href')
  name = urlparse.urlparse(url).path.split('/')[-1]
  dirname = urlparse.urlparse(url).path.split('.')[-1]
  f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  s = f.read()
  if (os.path.isdir(dirname) == 0): 
    os.mkdir(dirname)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
  articleTag = soup.html.body.article
  converted = str(articleTag)
  full_path = os.path.join(dirname, name)
  open(full_path, 'w').write(converted)
  print(name)
print("DOWNLOADS COMPLETE!")
```

links.html

```
<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.1.nmv-fas">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.1.nmv-fas</a>

<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.2.nmv-fas">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.2.nmv-fas</a>

<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.3.nmv-fas">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.3.nmv-fas</a>

<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.4.nmv-fas">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.4.nmv-fas</a>

<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.5.nmv-fas">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.5.nmv-fas</a>

<a href="http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.6.nmv-fas">http://www.youversion.com/bible/gen.6.nmv-fas</a>
```

Comment: What have you tried? [Here's a starting point](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#thread-objects). And [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131069/need-some-assistance-with-python-threading-queue).

Comment: I realize you asked for urllib but you might want to look at scrapy.  It is async at very mature it will allow you to make multiple requests with very very little effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blainer, try threading.

Here's a good practical example

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/

Then reference the python std library as well

http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html

If you look on the practical example it actually has a sample of threaded version of urllib2 concurrent downloads. I I went ahead and took you a few step more into the process, you will have to work with the part that says fix this to further parse your html out..

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import Queue
import threading
import urllib2
import time
import htmllib, formatter

class LinksExtractor(htmllib.HTMLParser):
    # derive new HTML parser

    def __init__(self, formatter):        
        # class constructor
        htmllib.HTMLParser.__init__(self, formatter)  
        # base class constructor
        self.links = []        
        # create an empty list for storing hyperlinks

    def start_a(self, attrs) :  # override handler of <A ...>...</A> tags
        # process the attributes
        if len(attrs) > 0 :
            for attr in attrs :
                if attr[0] == "href":         
                    # ignore all non HREF attributes
                    self.links.append(attr[1]) # save the link info in the list

    def get_links(self) :     
        # return the list of extracted links
        return self.links

format = formatter.NullFormatter()
htmlparser = LinksExtractor(format)

data = open("links.html")
htmlparser.feed(data.read())
htmlparser.close()

hosts = htmlparser.links

queue = Queue.Queue()

class ThreadUrl(threading.Thread):
    """Threaded Url Grab"""
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            #grabs host from queue
            host = self.queue.get()

            ####################################
            ############FIX THIS PART###########
            #VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV#

            url = urllib2.urlopen(host)
            morehtml = url.read() # your own your own with this

            #signals to queue job is done
            self.queue.task_done()

start = time.time()
def main():
    #spawn a pool of threads, and pass them queue instance 
    for i in range(5):
        t = ThreadUrl(queue)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

        #populate queue with data   
    for host in hosts:
        queue.put(host)

    #wait on the queue until everything has been processed     
    queue.join()

main()
print "Elapsed Time: %s" % (time.time() - start)
```

Comment: I looked at that, but my script only grabs one url at a time from links.html...how can I make the variable "url" get all of the links at once?

Comment: parse the html higher up in the script and create a list then when its time to download unleash the threads. ( I was going to say unleash hell but your downloading the bible! lol)

Comment: @dc5553 - I would never imagine that something on SO will make me laugh so much! :-D

Comment: Blainer come back for a present..still needs work but alot closer

Comment: In this post [Are urllib2 and httplib thread safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825151/are-urllib2-and-httplib-thread-safe), they discussed that urllib2 is not thread safe. They suggested using urllib3 in a thread.